# How to use Chrome Lighthouse to analyze a Node.js / backend code?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, code-analysis, lighthouse

Lighthouse, a part of the Chrome Developer Tools, provides great reports and analytics for the app frontend code.

I'm curious to know, is it possible to apply Lighthouse on a code, running on Node.js, in other words, is it possible to use a power of Lighthouse for analyzing a backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lighthouse wouldn't work for NodeJS. There a lot of things in lighthouse that wouldn't be applicable to backend code, such as SEO improvements etc.

Comment: Yes, I guess, but Lighthouse has also performance-related metrics.

Comment: Yeah that's fair enough, you'll probably want to look at a profiling tool, give this a read and see if it helps. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/ and something like https://clinicjs.org/ 

And in terms of code style etc, you could look at eslint and the airbnb config